# MySQL LOAD XML import performance

Tags: mysql, xml

Is it a good idea to use `LOAD XML` to import XML data into MySQL tables? Are there knows issues or significant performance improvements in later MySQL versions (I'm using 5.5.34)?

My current test run using about 50 MB of XML and simple, empty InnoDB tables with one index each suggests that the performance is really bad - about 3 to 8 writes or 8 KB per second on a Core i7 notebook with SSD. Given that performance, it would take about 80 days to import all my data (20 mio rows) while the goal is about 4 to 8 hours.

The SQL code looks like this:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'import.xml' 
  REPLACE INTO TABLE assets ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<asset>';
```

The MySQL server runs on CentOS 6.3 in VMware Fusion. All files are located within that VM, so the host FS is not accessed during import.

Comment: Well I’d guess that a “simpler” format like CSV would be easier to parse and therefor most likely import quicker. As for your indexes on the tables, could you drop those and only add them after the import? That should speed things up a little as well, provided you don’t need the indexes at time of the import to avoid duplicates or foreign key checks.

Comment: What tuning have you done on your MySQL configuration? The default config is actually really awful. Also, have you compared the relative speed of CSV to XML to see if the format is the issue?

Comment: I could not get it faster than 3 writes/s, even with more recent MySQL versions and without a VM. The regular CSV import was really fast however: up to 2500 writes/s without any tuning and with the same tables. I need the index, since we're doing a replace based on the primary key (can you really use InnoDB without PK?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use LOAD DATA INFILE and not LOAD XML INFILE, which seems to suffer from severe performance issues in all MySQL versions. See comment.

This change was not a huge problem for me, since I'm using XSLT to create the input file(s). XML would have been easier and more flexible, but XSLT allows to create plain text output (CSV/TSV) as well.